# Can Thrift maintain Memcached persistent connection in php

Tags: php, c++, memcached, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am writing one c++ client which using my PHP Thrift server.

I want Thrift persistent communicate with client to server.

And Thrift can communicate client & server persistent connection but inside my PHP Thrift server I am using Memcached server and it can be also persistent. Mostly PHP Memcached persistent connection maintained by web server.

So can my PHP Thrift server maintain Memcached persistent connection ?

If not should I have to use any other language like which make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To connect to Memcached, you have to use some kind of connector which is able to talk to Memcached using it's own protocol [described here](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt). This protocol is completely different from anything that Thrift supports today.

However, you may want to use Thrift to serialize your data before storing them into Memcached. That would be an absolutely valid and reasonable use case. Especially as you are already using Thrift for the C++/PHP connection and because this would enable you to access the data from both C++ and PHP without too much hassle, if the latter is needed.

<sub>Unfortunately, Memcached does not (yet) offer a Thrift service API, which is honestly not such a bad idea in my opinion.</sub>